# Changing the value with in CSS at runtime ( specifically .Net )

Tags: c#, css, .net, http, assets

Lets say I have a css which has reference to another asset say an image.
E.g abc.css contains.
background: url(/a/rfp/images/logo.png) no-repeat;

Now I want to change the url at run-time to point to some other domain say :

background: url(http://cdn1.domain.com/a/rfp/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
This cdn1.domain.com will come from a variable. And this can be changed at run-time also
say 
background: url(http://cdn2.domain2.com/a/rfp/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
So what makes sense is to bind this domain using a variable.

I can generate css using build time.
Any templatization solution ? Or anything else.
Point to remember is : the domain name can change at runtime. So for each HTTP request, one can change the variable and therefore, domain name.

Comment: Why not to put CSS there too - it is easier to change path to CSS in HTML (which most likely dynamically generated with ASPX/CSHTML)than dynamically create CSS... Anyway what exactly you are looking for CSS? just basic `String.Replace` and service via `return Content(changeString, "text/css") for MVC would work...

Comment: Have heard about `.less`??

Comment: Depends what you are looking at doing it for.. this might help.. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx - use scriptmananger in .net to switch local or cdn.

Comment: All of you have given good answer. But the issue is something else.
let me explain it again.
The css file name is : abc.css
which contains references to an image
http://cdn1.domain.com/a/rfp/images/logo.png
Where this value http://cdn1.domain.com/ has to come from a variable.
So I can't keep the whole css to any cdn because browser directly pulls it. And it will have hard-coded cdn1.domain.com domain only. I can't change it different for each http request.
Now if I have to serve css from server I think .less is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Im not sure of the need for this so the solution might not be perfect.. but...

For the css file in question.. Change it to an aspx page and add `<% Response.ContentType = "text/css" %>` to the top of the file. Then you can use URL parameters to change values within the file. These url parameters can be changes as needed by your application by amending what the url to the file is in the master page.

This will mean you cant bundle the css file in question, but then it would be hard to bundle a file that changes at runtime as you want it to anyway.